# Setting an address directly to Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

There is an requirment that i have to update the pointer during runtime, so written code like for checking.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
     int *ptr = NULL;
     int var = 10;
     ptr = &var;
     printf ("\nvalue is %d\t", ptr);
     printf ("\nvalue is %d\t", &var);
     printf ("\nvalue is %d\t", *ptr);
     int add = &var;
     ptr = (int*)add;
     printf ("\nvalue is %d\t", ptr); //printing address of var, which is expected
     printf ("\nvalue is %d\t", *ptr); //segmentation fault in this line
     printf ("\nvalue is %d\t", add);

    return 0;
}
```

if i print pointer, address of var was correctly present. But why *ptr gives seg fault? It should not be the value of var = 10?

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: And what if ints are not the samesize as a pointer?

Comment: An `int` is not necessarily big enough to hold a pointer.  This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you **actually** trying to accomplish?

Comment: That you have to "update the pointer during runtime" is a very vague requirement. You should ask whoever gave you the task for clarification.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and consider the warnings you get as errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here:

```
int add = &var;
```

Should be:

```
int* add = &var;
```

Otherwise the address gets truncated when you try to assign it to an `int`, which very likely is smaller than a pointer. Your compiler should give you all kinds of type mismatch/indirection level warnings.

Also note that the correct format specifier for printing a pointer is `%p`, not `%d`.